# Splunk - To search for concurrent run of processes

Tags: concurrency, transactions, splunk

I want to check if there are multiple instances of a job/process running .

Ex: My Splunk search :

```
index=abc <jobname> |  stats earliest(_time) AS earliest_time, latest(_time) AS latest_time count by  source | convert ctime(earliest_time), ctime(latest_time) | sort - count
```

returns :

```
source   earliest_time       latest_time          count
logA     06/06/2020 15:24:09 06/06/2020 15:24:59      1
logB     06/06/2020 15:24:24 06/06/2020 15:25:12      2
```

In the above since logB indicates job run before logA completion time,  it is indication of concurrent run of process. I would like to generate a list of all such jobs if it is possible , any help is appreciated .
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an inbuilt Splunk command for this, `concurrency`. This command requires an event start time and the duration, which we can calculate as the difference between the earliest and latest times. This command will create a new field called `concurrency` which is a *measurement represent[ing] the total number of events in progress at the time that each particular event started, including the event itself*.

```
index=abc <jobname> | stats earliest(_time) as et latest(_time) as lt count by source | eval duration=lt-et | concurrency start=et duration=duration | where concurrency>1
```

Docs for `concurrency` can be found at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/SearchReference/Concurrency

Comment: Thanks Simon. This is helpful . I have a followup question on this : I want to check concurrent runs & the corresponding job across board. Ex: JOB1 has logA & logB with concurrent timings, JOB2 has logC & log D with concurrent timings. i.e., based on jobname, can this solution be extended .I do not want concurrency check to happen between logC & logA since they belong to different jobs. Thank you for help.

Comment: Is there a Job field in the event? if so, we can probably include that field in the `by` clause of the `stats` command. Post a few events and we can see what the best approach would be